# Mean of largest and smallest number in a list of three numbers that are inputted

Tags: python, mean

I am trying to figure out how to find the average of the largest and smallest number out of three numbers that are inputted into the program.

```py
number1 = int(input('Enter First number : '))
number2 = int(input('Enter Second number : '))
number3 = int(input('Enter Third number : '))
def largest(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 > num2) and (num1 > num3):
        largest_num = num1
    elif (num2 > num1) and (num2 > num3):
        largest_num = num2
    else:
        largest_num = num3
    print("The largest of the 3 numbers is : ", largest_num)
def smallest(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 < num2) and (num1 < num3):
        smallest_num = num1
    elif (num2 < num1) and (num2 < num3):
        smallest_num = num2
    else:
        smallest_num = num3
    print("The smallest of the 3 numbers is : ", smallest_num)
largest(number1, number2, number3)
smallest(number1, number2, number3)
```

I am struggling to figure out how to find the mean of the smallest number and the largest number. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: `(largest(number1, number2, number3) +smallest(number1, number2, number3))/2`

Comment: `(largest_num + smallest_num) / 2` ?

Comment: What do you understand about the term `mean`? Have you tried anything to perform this calculation?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use `max()` and `min()`? Then just add your values to a list and `mean = (max(values) + min(values)) / 2`

Comment: Well, you could write `( min(number1, number2, number3) + max(number1, number2, number3) ) / 2`, but I'm not sure whether you're allowed to use max and min functions.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC the mean is all the numbers added and then divided by the number of terms you added.

Lets say I entered 1, 2, and 3 for each of the inputs. I would add the max and min up to get 4 and then divide that by 2(there are 2 numbers I added together, min and max) to get the mean average of 2 (4/2 = 2).

Heres your modified code:

```
number1 = int(input('Enter First number : '))
number2 = int(input('Enter Second number : '))
number3 = int(input('Enter Third number : '))

def largest(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 > num2) and (num1 > num3):
        largest_num = num1
    elif (num2 > num1) and (num2 > num3):
        largest_num = num2
    else:
        largest_num = num3
    print("The largest of the 3 numbers is : ", largest_num)
    return largest_num

def smallest(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 < num2) and (num1 < num3):
        smallest_num = num1
    elif (num2 < num1) and (num2 < num3):
        smallest_num = num2
    else:
        smallest_num = num3
    print("The smallest of the 3 numbers is : ", smallest_num)
    return smallest_num

def mean(large, small):
   sum = large+small
   res = sum/2
   print(f'The mean of the largest and smallest number is {res}')
   return res

largest = largest(number1, number2, number3)
smallest = smallest(number1, number2, number3)

mean = mean(largest, smallest)
```

By adding the `return` at the end of the function, you can make a variable off of it(`variable = function(args)` for example). That means you can use that variable later for other functions. With that, `mean` is now a variable that equals the mean of the numbers.
Hope this helps.

[Mean Formula(Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=mean%20math&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS1004US1005&ei=Vk5lY9HbHbTj5NoP3uaW8Ag&ved=0ahUKEwjR3tz0iJX7AhW0MVkFHV6zBY4Q4dUDCBE&uact=5&oq=mean%20math&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIICAAQgAQQsQMyCAgAEIAEELEDMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQ6CggAEEcQ1gQQsAM6BwgAELADEEM6DQgAEOQCENYEELADGAE6DwguENQCEMgDELADEEMYAjoECAAQQzoHCAAQsQMQQzoLCC4QgAQQsQMQ1AI6CAguELEDEIAEOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToFCC4QgARKBAhNGAFKBAhBGABKBAhGGAFQxQJYlghgqwloAXABeACAAVGIAd4CkgEBNZgBAKABAcgBEsABAdoBBggBEAEYCdoBBggCEAEYCA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp&surl=1&safe=active&ssui=on#wptab=si:AC1wQDCDyRf_4m8Q8nhldHMjdIalRktweLkw15mQu4pgD74-zTPd143G2jPPfdHofxO-bVXhOY-O5RuUuoDnvywB2YDqTBgWJRdiRl3xL-jlU7H_lVfXftf7sg030aRNAomT8xKbn-wU)

Comment: OP is wanting the mean of the smallest and largest number, not the mean of all three.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding then, just the mean average of max and min? Given my example, would he want it to be (3 + 1)/2? I can't think of anything else...

Comment: Yep. That's all OP is looking for. Very simple to solve for, but they may be struggling with the meaning of `mean`? Not sure.

Comment: Gotcha. Updated my post with all the code he should need. Thanks for your help